# SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) install into existing Eclipse install via the update site not working

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I'm trying to install SpringSource Tool Suite into an existing Eclipse install (3.7 Indigo). Following the update site manual from SpringSource, everything runs ok, however I cannot find any way to open the SpringSource Dashboard or the welcome screen (the green background).

In Window > Open Perspective > Other... there is no entry for Spring.

Going to the new menu I can't even create a new Spring project.

I have used the tool suite before as a standalone install, however I now want to play around with Spring Roo and use my current eclipse install and config.

Checking the install new software manager, everything says its installed and going into Help > About Eclipse shows all the Spring logos as suggested by the install guide.

Any ideas on what has gone wrong, or how I can figure out what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try creating a new Eclipse workspace with your newly installed STS?

Comment: Just made an account to add that LightCC's answer saved hours- STS 4.1.0 installation was perfect, with no issues, but Spring options were just not populating till I followed their steps and installed STS 3.9.7 also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does sound like something is not installed correctly.

First, have a look at your error log.  Any interesting errors?  Also, try restarting and seeing if any new errors come out.

If that doesn't show anything interesting, then it would be good to see what is installed.  Can you go to Help -> About Eclipse -> Installed Software?  Select all and copy.  Paste it into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go **Help -> Check For Updates** and repeat that process.

Secondarily, go into **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace** and search for STS. If it is installed, it will say **Installed** on the button on the bottom right - but click on it anyway, and you will have some options that might show you that some components might need to be upgraded.  I had to do this with the STS 4 plugin I had installed.

And for those installing with STS 4 available - it will NOT give the Spring perspective or populate most of the Spring items in the "File / New" menu.  It only appears to provide a few Spring boot items. You still have to install STS 3 as well to get most items to show up right in Eclipse, at least as of STS 4.1.0.